# How to view vertices on model when not showing

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, vertices

I have the model from the bellow image and when I'm entering Edit mode, I can't see any vertices. How can I enable them? I want to remove some parts of it. If I add a simple cube, on that I can see them. Does it have something to do with the model and it can't be changed?

[image: Model]

This is the wireframe view:

[image: Wireframe]

All the tutorials I've seen start with them on and tell you how to move/delete, and none of them talk about the situation when they aren't showing.

Comment: it looks like you've selected the armature, not the character object, if you want to edit the character, switch back to Object mode, select the character, switch to Edit mode, then choose the Vertex Select mode, press Alt Z if you want transparency

Comment: You are right, thank you. I'm not "character/actor maker", so even something simple like this will cause problems for me. I'm only using blender when I really have to. Make your comment as an answer to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've selected the armature, not the character object, if you want to edit the character, switch back to *Object* mode, select the character, switch to *Edit* mode, then choose the *Vertex Select* mode, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> if you want transparency.